# Как запустить функцию после выполнения ряда ajax запросов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить такую задачу.
Есть на странице 5 элементов, которые при клике на кнопку я должен обновить, с помощью ajax запросов, и сразу же после обновления всех 5 полей, запустить следующую функцию.
Я сделал глобальную переменную `count = 5`, и в блоке `success` ajax запроса, декрементирую глобальную переменную. Но как дальше мне повесить монитор или что-то на его подобии, который сможет следить за этой переменной.
Использовать callback я так понял бесполезно здесь.

Comment: если вы можете и уменьшать переменную, то и на 0 наверное там же можете проверить? а можете сделать ее объектом с сеттером, который проверит.

Comment: смогу и на 0 проверить, но функции с ajax запросами работают не только в данной реализации.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/promise#parallelnoe-vypolnenie или же просто Promise.all

Comment: все это хорошо, но у меня идут не просто ajax запросы, скажем происходит запуск функций, в которых есть определенная реализация и после запуск ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за помощь. Решил проблему так. Создал новую функцию, где не просто декрементирую переменную `count`, но и проверяю после на 0, если равна 0, то стартую следующую функцию.

Comment: а что будет если повторно нажать на кнопку?

Comment: сработает заново